# How to increase responses to comments that request clarification information?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, comments

I've encountered lots of questions on SO which aren't very well phrased or don't contain enough information to exactly understand what is being asked. If the question is interesting it's followed by one or a few comments from users asking for clarifications or additional information which... get no response, none whatsoever.

The question is simply abandoned by the OP.

What might be some ideas to improve this and encourage the OP to respond? I'm thinking something similar to flagging the question with "needs extra info" that adds a link to some page in the FAQ to explain to the OP what to do next.

Comment: Downvote, vote to close and move on.

Comment: You cannot ever *force* someone to respond. Just vote to close the question if it is not clear enough and move on. The close reason already includes the FAQ info.

Comment: @Yannis: That's pretty much the first thought that comes to mind but this way the OP doesn't learn anything and will continue doing it. I don't know if this is me but I have the feeling that some people take the request for extra info as a form of rejection or something and are afraid to touch the question so they don't make it worse... At least that's what I think happens. Closing is terminal.

Comment: @JohnDoDo: Closing is *not* terminal. Questions can always be reopened. But we cannot indefinitely wait for someone to come back and conquer their fear. **We** cannot look into their heads and see what the question really is about.

Comment: @JohnDoDo: The bottom line is that we cannot save *every* bad question. Closing is the right action here; if the OP has the motivation and a genuine question worth posting, then they can recover from that state. If not, then so be it, but we get to keep the site clean and focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm thinking something similar to flagging the question with "needs extra info" that adds a link to some page in the FAQ to explain to the OP what to do next.

This is what closing a question is for.

The on-hold / close notice includes links to the FAQ about how to improve the question for re-opening *already*.

You cannot force anyone to respond; if they don't respond to requests for clarification in the comments, then voting to close is *entirely* the correct response.