# How about 'Request Clarification?'

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions

TLDR: Let responders request clarification rather than comment, 3: Profit.

Reading a short question just now, and my response is not an answer but a question asking for clarification.

Usually people ask for clarification in the comments, and the asker updates the question, leaving the comments either out of date, or removed etc etc.

So can I request a "Request clarification" feature where I can ask for a specific bit of information? This could be upvoted by others who also think this needs to be clarified, much as the equivalent comment would be.

Crucially, though, the asker could then respond to the clarification specifically, and anyone who had upvoted that request would be notified in their inbox.

Related: [How to increase responses to comments that request clarification information?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203823/how-to-increase-responses-to-comments-that-request-clarification-information), [How to ask for a clarification in a old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105150/how-to-ask-for-a-clarification-in-a-old-question)

A final thought is that a question could be put on hold until requests for clarification are answered, for questions that could be worthwhile but not without further information.

Comment: What would be the rules for putting on hold? Four upvotes on any pending clarification request?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of complication for something already handled by comments. As for the on-hold suggestion - I can see so much potential for abuse.

Comment: The out of date comments are handled by flagging them as obsolete. Removing them is... well, what should happen - they're out of date and serve little current value.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need for this.

You can (and should) already request clarification of questions and answers through the comments and voting to close a question as "unclear" does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented simply by having a checkbox when making a comment, that states 'For Clarification'.  Then the OP could have some way of noting that he has made a clarification, and the comment poster would be notified.  Even simpler would be to just notify based on an edit.

You could implement this in the interface by adding another icon that the OP would use to show that a clarification has been made, and other users could use so that they would also get clarification.  The linked users would be cleared after the OP has noted the clarification.

TLDR process:

1. User asks for clarification in comment and checks 'Clarification'
   checkbox
2. Icon is highlighted showing this is a request for clarification
3. Other users agreeing with this, and interested in seeing the
   question clarified, click on icon
4. OP edits question to clarify (or just comments), then clicks the
   icon to show question is clarified
5. Original comment poster and all who clicked on the icon are notified
   of clarification

Note, step 4 could also have when an edit or comment by OP is made, a dialog asking if it answers specific clarifications.

Possible look:

[image: Clarification Icon]